# jQuery Listener Excluding Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionlistener

I have a dl list of dd items.  Each dd item has a listener attached to it (see below) so if it is clicked on I can rebuild the page and change some stuff.  Each of these dd items also have a checkbox within them though which I would like to be excluded from that listener (so it can be picked up by another listener).

The problem that is occuring is whenever I click anywhere in the dd it will apply the dd listener, not the checkbox listener even if I clicked on the checkbox.  Is there a way to distinguish what exactly was clicked without setting up divs inside the dd and applying listeners individually?

Example HTML Code:

```
<dl>
  <dd class="class1 class2 class3">Some text and stuff 
    <input type="checkbox" class="class1 checkBox">
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Example jQuery Code:

```
$("class1.checkbox").live("click", function() {
  //Do some other, completely different, cool stuff
  //console.log($(this).parent().attr("id"));
  console.log("test");
});

$("dd.class1.class2").live("click", function () {
  //Do some cool stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox").live("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
  //Do some other, completely different, cool stuff
  //console.log($(this).parent().attr("id"));
  alert("test");
});

$("dd.class1.class2").live("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  //Do some cool stuff
    alert("test2");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PsaHQ/4/

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop the event bubbling.

```
$(".class1:checkbox").click(function(e) {
    alert('clicked checkbox');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("dd.class1.class2").click(function () {
    alert('clicked dd');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

The concept of "bubbling up" is like if you have a child element with a click event and you don't want it to trigger the click event of the parent. You could use `event.stopPropagation()`.

`event.stopPropagation()` basically says only apply this click event to THIS CHILD NODE and don't tell the parent containers anything because I don't want them to react.

**Event Capturing:**

```
               | |
---------------| |-----------------
| element1     | |                |
|   -----------| |-----------     |
|   |element2  \ /          |     |
|   -------------------------     |
|        Event CAPTURING          |
-----------------------------------
```

**Event Bubbling:**

```
               / \
---------------| |-----------------
| element1     | |                |
|   -----------| |-----------     |
|   |element2  | |          |     |
|   -------------------------     |
|        Event BUBBLING           |
-----------------------------------
```

If you are using `live()` or `delegate()` you will need to `return false;`, though it may not work. Read the quote below.

Per [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate
>   to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on
>   any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed
>   by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers,
>   therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by
>   calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

A good resource: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: The only reason I am using .live() is because the html is all dynamically generated after the fact.  Any other option then? Just using .click was not working before.

Comment: Stop using `live()`. Use `delegate()` instead. It may or may not prevent the propagation depending on your application and where you bind your events.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you've got a bunch of little problems adding up to a big one here.

Your first selector has 2 issues in it.  Look at the updated selector below (and notice the capitalization):

```
$(".class1.checkBox").live("click", function() {
  //Do some other, completely different, cool stuff
  console.log("test");
  return false; //added.
});
```

If you want to stop the event from bubbling to the next jquery listener, just return false.

Answer (score 1):

Just bind the click event to the dd and check the target delegate appropriately

```
  $("dd.class1.class2").live("click", function (event) {
        if($(event.target).is(":checkbox"))
        {
            console.log("put checkbox func here");
        }else{
           console.log("put div func here");
        }
    });
```

Working Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QWLpd/1/